# What is the default file path used by the Put function and how do I pre-evaluate an expression to use in Put?

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, data-format

I have a problem of trying to store some output in an external file.

In one note book I define a function `f[x_]:=AdvancedCalculation`, where this function generates a relatively large output and is dependent on a significant number of definitions. In another notebook, I would like to have the expression `terms=f[x]`, but I do not want to actually calculate `f[x]` more than once because it would take too long. Currently I have stored the output of `f[x]` in a file called `Terms.m` that has a single line of code.

```
terms=OutputFromOtherNotebook
```

I then load this file in my second notebook using the command `<<Terms.m`.

My current solution is to copy and paste `OutputFromOtherNotebook` directly from the first notebook into the file `Terms.m`. I would like to automate this process because larger outputs have become too cumbersome. I am trying to use `Put` to write the output using the following line of code.

```
terms=Evaluate[f[x]]>>Terms.m
```

However, I cannot find the resulting file. Where does the function `Put` create the file? As a side issue, how can I ensure that `f[x]` is evaluated before being written to the external file?

Comment: `Put` outputs to whatever directory is returned by `Directory[]`, which is by default your home directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carl has shown a way to write to the file what you want, but I would suggest to not even put the `terms=` into the file: you can read the expression and set it to a variable when reading it. It will also get rid of all kinds of complications that occure if you want to write partially evaluated expressions. This approach lets you choose the name of the variable at the time of reading which I think is an advantage as it will make it somewhat simpler to e.g. compare the content of two such files in one session.

As for the directory using `SetDirectory` is also a perfectly valid solution, but I would suggest to just use full pathes for the files which gives you more control about the location and is much easier to understand and debug, as it is "free" of the current "state" of what the working directory is set to. This is what I'd do:

```
f[x_] := Expand[(a + b)^100];
fname = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Terms.m"}];
Put[f[x], fname];
```

using `NotebookDirectory` will store "Terms.m" in the same directory as the notebook this is running in, which is very often what you want. You can of course use whatever other directory you want. I'd suggest to look through the predefined directories instead of typing in long machine specific directory names, there are e.g. variables for your home directory, the temporary directory or your documents directory. You can find all predefined directory names by evaluating this:

```
?$*Directory*
```

If you already have evaluated `f[x]` and don't want to rerun it, you might want to use something like:

```
Put[%,fname]
```

if the output was the last result calculated. Using something like the following is more robust, as it is independent on how many other things have been evaluated since the call to `f[x]`:

```
Put[Out[123],fname]
```

where the output number (123 in the example) you can read from the output cell tag (these labels can be suppressed in the preferences and it also might not work if you have set `$HistoryLength` to a low value, it should work with the default settings, though).

To read the expression, just set `terms` to the return value of `Get`, as this:

```
terms = Get[fname];
```

You might note that `<<` and `>>` are just shortcuts for `Get` and `Put` but will implicitly read the "argument" as a string (`<< something` is actually equivalent to `Get["something"]`). So you can't use the shortcuts with a filename stored in a variable as I did, which is a good reason to use the full function names and not the shortcuts...

Comment: I agree with you that your answer is probably better *Mathematica* style. It certainly produces a slightly more robust approach for the specific issue I was considering when I wrote the original question. I also think your mention about the built in variables and functions for handling directory names is more robust.

Answer (score 3):

As @R.M. said in the comment, the function `Put` places the file into the directory returned by `Directory[]`. This location can be changed by using the function `SetDirectory`.

I do not know of a way to directly write the expression `terms=OutputFromOtherNotebook` into `Terms.m` using `Put`, but I do have a method using the function `Write`. The following code writes the desired expression to `Terms.m`.

```
WriteString[OpenWrite["Terms.m"], "terms=", InputForm@f[x]]
Close["Terms.m"];
```

The function OpenWrite["Terms.m"] opens the file `Terms.m` as an output stream. The function `WriteString` writes the contents of the string "terms=" literally into `Terms.m`, and then it writes the value returned by `f[x]` as input form so that the string can be written directly following the previous string, resulting in the desired expression. The function `Close` then closes the output stream opened earlier.

This method has the effect of only executing the function `f` when the file is written, and not when `Terms.m` is loaded. The use of `InputForm` is important to ensure that exponents are written in the form `x^y` by `WriteString` rather than it's default format, which is as follows.

```
 y
x
```

This unusual form would not allow the output to be read correctly using `Get`.